# How do I define a while loop in a function and call it multiple times in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop

I have a `while` loop

```
string path = "";
int ctr = 0, i = 0;
while (i < lvwArticles.Items.Count)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = lvwArticles.Items[i];
    if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text != path)
    {
        path = lvi.SubItems[2].Text;
        ctr = 0;
        skipme = false;
    }
    if (!skipme)
    {
        ctr++;

        lvi.EnsureVisible();
        lvi.Checked = true;
    }
        //Process
    i++;
}

private void function1()
{
    while()
    {
        //Process
    }
}

private void function2()
{
    while()
    {
        //Process
    }
}

private void function3()
{
    while()
    {
        //Process
    }
}

private void function4()
{
    while()
    {
        //Process
    }
}

private void function5()
{
    while()
    {
        //Process
    }
}
```

I have 5 `functions` in my program that need this `while` loop. So, is there a way that I can declare this `while` loop in a separate function and call it as and when needed?

The `//Process` is variable. So, I have multiple different actions in different functions, but all of them need to be done within the same `while` loop.

Comment: Can you confirm is it **recursive** behaviour you want?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass in a Action into the while loops? If it's the case, just wrap the while loop with a method then accept the Action<> as parameter.

Comment: It may or may not be recursive. So, I will break it down for you. The `loop` reads the number of files that appear in the `ListView` mentioned. Depending on the input, I am calling different functions to run on the list of files. As mentioned, I have 5 functions. All of them need to read the files in the `ListView` and then process further.

Comment: I would probably refactor the code so that reading the files and returning the read result becomes a separate function (maybe using `yield return`) and the outer function would just work on the read results in a separate loop. Separation of concerns - don't mix many tasks into one piece of code (like reading some input and processing its result).

Comment: @Omanshu - that comment is better than your question! Please [edit] the question with the additional info, people volunteering to help shouldn't need to go through comments. All clarifications should be added to question. Just the way it works around here. Good luck!

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I understand your point. I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 3):

> The //Process is variable. So, I have multiple different actions in different functions, but all of them need to be done within the same while loop.

Yes you can. It's called an `Action`:

```
public void YourFunction(Action action)
{
    string path = "";
    int ctr = 0, i = 0;
    while (i < lvwArticles.Items.Count)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = lvwArticles.Items[i];
        if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text != path)
        {
            path = lvi.SubItems[2].Text;
            ctr = 0;
            skipme = false;
        }
        if (!skipme)
        {
            ctr++;

            lvi.EnsureVisible();
            lvi.Checked = true;
        }

        //Process
        action();

        i++;
    }
}
```

Now you can pass in the process you want to execute at that moment:

```
YourFunction(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello"));
```

Comment: Or `Func<T>`, since the action most likely depend on some data within the loop

Answer (score 1):

> I have 5 functions in my program that need this while loop. So, is there a way that I can declare this while loop in a separate function and call it as and when needed?

This is to demonstrate recursive behaviour I asked about in the comments:

```
private void LoadTree(ListView lstViewChild)
{
string path = "";
int ctr = 0, i = 0;
while (i < lstViewChild.Count)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = lstViewChild.Items[i];
    if (lvi.SubItems[2].Text != path)
    {
        path = lvi.SubItems[2].Text;
        ctr = 0;
        skipme = false;

        //I think its here where you want to recursively call it
        LoadTree(lvi);  //<-- here we call this method again, be careful as each time you call it, it add to the call stack and when you exhaust that it results in a STACKOVERFLOW exception!
    }
    if (!skipme)
    {
        ctr++;

        lvi.EnsureVisible();
        lvi.Checked = true;
    }
        //Process



    i++;
}
}
```